# How to setup call only mode

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Miss this feature from my old 'Berry - easily set to Phone Call Only mode overnight so support calls from work ring through but text/email notifications are silent. Is there a way to have similar one touch on/off functionality?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use blocking mode. A feature in the Samsung TouchWiz devices (I believe made available in 4.0).

Settings -> Blocking Mode

- Enable blocking mode
- Uncheck "Disable incoming calls"
- Set the time that blocking mode should be enabled
- Sleep until the phone rings

[image: Blocking Mode]

If you still want to actually receive the notifications for email and text messages you can do the following:

- Go to Settings -> Sound
- Select Volume
- Turn up Ringtone
- Turn down all the others

[image: Volume]

While these are not "one touch", you can do the second one right from the home screen.

- Just hit the volume button
- hit the button to expand the volume controls
- adjust the volume of all the settings

Comment: The blocking mode was added in the 4.1 jelly bean update, which should be available to pretty much everyone by now.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this easily by using [Timeriffic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic). All you have to do is setup a new time triggered task. At the set time, you can make the *notification volume* to zero. After the set time you can make it change the volume back to normal level

I suppose you want to *mute* the notification sounds rather than disabling them.

Answer (score 0):

I came from BlackBerry too and I've used the [Quick Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=quick%20profiles) app on my Atrix for exactly this purpose, and you can create multiple profiles.

- to allow phone calls to come through at night while muting all else.

It's free and offers a lot of flexibility (e.g., settings such as screen time-out, brightness, etc.)